# Resize image after capture it from native camera but before save it to SD card

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I am opening a default Camera in my app on button click.when i click on button ,it works fine.But it capture the image of default size and I want to re-size the image before save it in SD card after capture it from default camera.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following piece of code to set proper width and height for camera intent.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
    intent.putExtra("outputX",
            width_of_output_image);
    intent.putExtra("outputY",
            height_of_output_image);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra( "scale", true );
            startActivityForResult( intent, 1 );
```

Comment: Hi TrickSter..thanks for answering it.But actually I want to compress the image instead of scale it.Can u plz help me?

Comment: For scaling down an image, please refer to this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
I think, you cant use it with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE you have to resize the returned bitmap i.e. full size image in case you didnt give EXTRA_OUTPUT otherwise you have to read image from your uri and resize then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must help you:-

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BitmapFactory.Options optionsSignature = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    final Bitmap bitmapSignature = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
            fileUriSignature.getPath(), optionsSignature);

    Bitmap resizedSignature = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmapSignature, 256, 128, true);

    signature.setImageBitmap(resizedSignature);
```