# Resize captured image before save

Tags: java, android, size, android-camera

I'm trying to resize the captured image so that it can has a size smaller than 1Mb. This is what I'm tried so far in **OnActivityResult** but failed. I'm get the tutorial from [Android take photo and resize it before saving on sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060143/android-take-photo-and-resize-it-before-saving-on-sd-card)

**ImageFitScreen.java**

```
 try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    bitmapOptions.inDither = true;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
                    Global.img = bitmap;

                    b.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    //p = path;
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");
                    try {

                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outFile);
                        //pic=file;
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
```

**Claims.java**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    byte[] data=getBitmapAsByteArray(getActivity(),Global.img);// this is a function
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(data==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SB.insertStaffBenefit(name, data, description, result, fk);
                    }

        });
        return claims;
    }

    public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(final Context context,Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        Toast.makeText(context, outputStream.size()/1024+"KB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

**In Claims.java, it still display the size which is more than 1Mb**

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "failed" means. For example, are you crashing? If so, use LogCat to examine your Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm so sorry. I have edited my post.

Comment: is this the correct way to implement?  Or I implemented in the wrong places?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link below

[How to resize Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

For better UI give toast to the user asking to upload image of specific size still he uploads larger image check it in backend or server and give negative response or prompt hi to again upload image of smaller size.